# JavaScript play sound when user/tab/browser is inactive

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, playback

I am using the following code to play sound when user receives a message AND the user is not in the tab mean that the current tab is INACTIVE or user is outside current tab.

```
$(window).hover(function(event) {
    if (event.fromElement) {
        console.log("inactive");
    } else {
        console.log("active");
        beep("beep.wav", 1.0); //your code here
    }
});
```

I want to play the sound only when user is away from tab and NOT when he is inside the tab. Right now the sound only plays when the user comes back to the tab. This is not what i want.

I can see facebook and gmail does this even if user is outside in another tab, How do they do it?

I searched on SO but couldn't find any answer for this!

Help me!

Answer (score 1):

I imagine something like:

```js
var intervalHandler = null;

$(window).blur(function(e) {
  intervalHandler = window.setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementById('beep').play();
    window.clearInterval(intervalHandler);
  }, 1000);
});
$(window).focus(function(e) {
  window.clearInterval(intervalHandler);
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>


<audio id="beep" src="http://www.soundjay.com/button/beep-07.wav" autostart="false" ></audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found from SO myself:

They disable the sound  when user tab is active:

```
var isactive = false;

function playSound(){
    if (isactive) return;
    playWav...;
}

onNotificaitonComes = playSound;

$(window).focus(function(){
    isactive = true;
}).blur(function(){
    isactive = false;
});
```